# Не работает код. Где ошибся?

Tags: python

Мне нужно найти все числа, у которых сумма двух наибольших собственных делителей равна 2019.

> **Собственный делитель - делитель не равный единице и самому числу**

Мой код:

```
def IsPrime(n):
   d = 2
   while n % d != 0:
       d += 1
   return d == n
def print_factors(x): 
       for i in range(1, x + 1): 
               if x % i == 0: 
                    s.append(i)
s=[]
for num in range(1,10000):
    print_factors(num)
    IsPrime(num)
    if IsPrime(num) == False:
        for element in s:
            if element == 1:
                s.remove(1)
            if element == num:
                s.remove(num)
        m = max(s)
        s.remove(m)
        k = max(s)
        if m + k == 2019:
            print(num)
```

В конце он просто ничего не выводит... в чем ошибка? Конечно таких чисел может и не быть, я пробовал подписать чтобы он выводил NO, если m + k != 2019, но даже этого не происходило..

Comment: Можно применить дедовский метод и выводить на печать промежуточные значения. Наверняка пара другая ошибок таким образом найдется.

Comment: И зачем записывать в s единицу и само число, чтобы их потом из s удалять?

Comment: ...да ещё таким странным способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой итерации цикла `for num in range(1,10000):` ваш `num` принимает значение `1`, потом применяете к этой единице вашу функцию `print_factors`, которая не возвращает **ничего**, т.к. условие `if x % i == 0` не выполняется